Will not run on postman no json response
When I run my code the specific json output does not show. For example like this:
{
 "id": 1,
 "name": "John Doe",
 "email": "john.doe@example.com",
 "bookings": [
 {
 "id": 101,
 "startDate": "2024-06-01",
 "endDate": "2024-06-10",
 "room": {
 "id": 201,
 "roomNumber": "101",
 "type": "Deluxe",
 "hotel": {
 "id": 301,
 "name": "Grand Hotel",
 "address": "123 Main St, Anytown"
 }
 },
 "payment": {
 "id": 401,
 "amount": 1500.00,
 "paymentDate": "2024-05-25",
 "paymentMethod": "Credit Card"
 }
} 

I tried creating a new resource class called test and it still doesn't work so the error seems to be within either my HTTP methods or my link which is " http://localhost:8080/HotelSystemAPI/rest/test ". Below is an example of my resource class, its dao and its model class.
    package com.mycompany.resource;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author aya
     */
    
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.*;
    import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
    import com.mycompany.model.*;
    import com.mycompany.dao.*;
    
    @Path("/payments")
    public class PaymentResource {
        // Create an instance of the PaymentDAO class:
        private PaymentDAO paymentDAO = new PaymentDAO();
    
        // GET request to return all payments:
        @GET
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public List<Payment> getAllPayments() {
            return paymentDAO.getAllPayments();
        }
    
        // GET request to return specific payment:
        @GET
        @Path("/{paymentId}")
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Payment getPaymentById(@PathParam("paymentId") int paymentId) {
            return paymentDAO.getPaymentById(paymentId);
        }
    
        // POST request to add a payment:
        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public void addPayment(Payment payment) {
            paymentDAO.addPayment(payment);
        }
    
        // PUT request to update a payment:
        @PUT
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Path("/{paymentId}")
        public void updatePayment(@PathParam("paymentId") int paymentId, Payment updatedPayment) {
            Payment existingPayment = paymentDAO.getPaymentById(paymentId);
            if (existingPayment != null) {
                updatedPayment.setPaymentId(paymentId);
                paymentDAO.updatePayment(updatedPayment);
            }
        }
    
        // DELETE request to delete a payment:
        @DELETE
        @Path("/{paymentId}")
        public void deletePayment(@PathParam("paymentId") int paymentId) {
            paymentDAO.deletePayment(paymentId);
        }
    }

    package com.mycompany.dao;
    
    /**
     *
     * @author aya
     */
    
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import com.mycompany.model.Payment;
    import com.mycompany.model.Booking;
    import com.mycompany.model.Customer;
    import com.mycompany.model.Room;
    
    public class PaymentDAO {
        // Data structure to store payments
        private static List<Payment> payments = new ArrayList<>();
    
        // Method to initialize sample data
        public static void initialiseData() {
            // Create instances of DAO classes
            CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO();
            BookingDAO bookingDAO = new BookingDAO();
            RoomDAO roomDAO = new RoomDAO();
    
            // Retrieve sample customers, bookings, and rooms
            List<Customer> customers = customerDAO.getAllCustomers();
            List<Booking> bookings = bookingDAO.getAllBookings();
            List<Room> rooms = roomDAO.getAllRooms();
    
            // Initialize sample payments
            payments.add(new Payment(1001, 1500.00, "2024-05-25", "Credit Card", customers.get(0), bookings.get(0)));
            payments.add(new Payment(1002, 2000.00, "2024-05-30", "Debit Card", customers.get(1), bookings.get(1)));
            // Add more sample payments as needed
        }
    
        // Method to return all payments
        public List<Payment> getAllPayments() {
            return payments;
        }
    
        // Method to return a specific payment by ID
        public Payment getPaymentById(int paymentId) {
            for (Payment payment : payments) {
                if (payment.getPaymentId() == paymentId) {
                    return payment;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    
        // Method to add a new payment
        public void addPayment(Payment payment) {
            payments.add(payment);
        }
    
        // Method to update an existing payment
        public void updatePayment(Payment updatedPayment) {
            for (int i = 0; i < payments.size(); i++) {
                if (payments.get(i).getPaymentId() == updatedPayment.getPaymentId()) {
                    payments.set(i, updatedPayment);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    
        // Method to delete a payment
        public void deletePayment(int paymentId) {
            payments.removeIf(payment -> payment.getPaymentId() == paymentId);
        }
    
        // Method to generate a new payment ID
        public int getNewPaymentId() {
            int maxId = 0;
            for (Payment payment : payments) {
                if (payment.getPaymentId() > maxId) {
                    maxId = payment.getPaymentId();
                }
            }
            return maxId + 1;
        }
    }

package com.mycompany.model;

/**
 *
 * @author aya
 */

public class Payment {
    //Variables
    private int paymentId;
    private double amount;
    private String paymentDate;
    private String paymentMethod;
    private Customer customer;
    private Booking booking;

    //First constructor:
    public Payment() {
    }
    
    //Second constructor:
    public Payment(int paymentId, double amount, String paymentDate, String paymentMethod, Customer customer, Booking booking) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
        this.customer = customer;
        this.booking = booking;
    }

    //Getter methods
    public int getPaymentId() {
        return paymentId;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public String getPaymentDate() {
        return paymentDate;
    }
    
    public String getPaymentMethod() {
        return paymentMethod;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }
    
    public Booking getBooking() {
        return booking;
    }
    
    //Setter methods
    public void setPaymentId(int paymentId) {
        this.paymentId = paymentId;
    }
        
    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
        
    public void setPaymentDate(String paymentDate) {
        this.paymentDate = paymentDate;
    }
        
    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    
    public void setPaymentMethod(String paymentMethod) {
        this.paymentMethod = paymentMethod;
    }
    
    public void setBooking(Booking booking) {
        this.booking = booking;
    }
    
}

